# Selecting distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get a selection of records where if COUNT ([WHO]) > 1 then select [WHO] where the [LIT] <> 0.

Example if [WHO] = '12082132' , '12082132' and [LIT] = 0, then ignore [WHO].

```
WHO        LIT  COUNT
3517015     7   1
3523687     0   1
12057744    0   2
12058316    7   1
12059820    7   1
12082132    2   2
12082132    5   1
12082132    1   3
12082132    14  1
12082132    0   1
```

I have tried grouping, case statements, but I think I am trying to get something that is not possible. Any help will do.

Expected results

```
 WHO           LIT  COUNT
    3517015     7   1
    12058316    7   1
    12059820    7   1
```

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Comment: You want to ignore entire [WHO] if [LIT] = 0 ? or just particular  row having [LIT] = 0 ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want? In my above list, I would not expect to return 12082132 or similar, but I would expect to return 12058316 or similar

Comment: And you want to return all the records of 12058316 right ? or just column [WHO] ?

Comment: Correct. All the records of 12058316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` & use *window* function :

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by t.who) as cnt
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1
                  where t1.who = t.who and t1.lit = 0
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to get a selection of records where if COUNT ([WHO]) > 1 then select [WHO] where the [LIT] <> 0.

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by who) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1 and lit <> 0;
```

Comment: . . . This will not returned `who`s which are not having lit = `0` neither matching with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Simple NOT IN will work

```
SELECT * FROM #Table 
WHERE [WHO] NOT IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT [WHO] 
                    FROM #Table
                   WHERE CASE WHEN [LIT] >= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1  END = 1
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, I hope it helps you,I think that it does what you want but its a little tricky, maybe can lead you to an answers at least if it's not 
what you want.

```
drop table #testMr
drop table #checkTest
create table #testMr(who numeric, lit numeric, count_x numeric)
create table #checkTest(who numeric, lit numeric, count_x numeric,countWho numeric)

insert into #testMr values(3517015,7,1)
insert into #testMr values(3523687,0,1)
insert into #testMr values(12057744,0,1)
insert into #testMr values(12058316,7,1)
insert into #testMr values(12082132,1,3)
insert into #testMr values(12082132,14,1)
insert into #testMr values(12082132,7,1)
insert into #testMr values(12082132,0,1)

insert into #checkTest
select who,sum(lit) as [lit],sum(count_x) as [CountX],count(who) as [CountWho] from #testMr  
where who in(select b.who from #testMr as b where b.lit<>0) group by who having count(who)>1

if(select count(*) from #checkTest)>0
begin
--there are some invalid values so we filter by the lit<>0 and remove the invalid ones.
    select * from #testMr where lit<>0 and who not in(select b.who from #checkTest as b)
end
else
begin
--'All values are Ok and we filter by the count who.'
    select who,sum(lit) as [lit],sum(count_x) as [CountX] from #testMr group by who having count(who)>1
end
```